# Как определить, какой шаблон подключён в данный момент?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте. Допустим в админке wordpress для главной страницы магазина назначен определённый шаблон, т.е. в котором есть Template Name: Имя шаблона.
В файле content-product.php, который вызывается по умолчанию для всех страниц магазина в цикле, я делаю проверку:

```
$classes = '';
if(is_page_template('content-main.php')){
    $woocommerce_loop['loop']++;
    if ($woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'product_cat') { ?>
```

Но эта проверка не срабатывает, т.е. вызывается стандартный код, расположенный в тегах li. А мне нужно обернуть товар в другие блоки, в зависимости от страницы и шорткода.
Файл content-main.php в данном случае является шаблон для главной страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_page_template()` не работает внутри цикла WordPress.

Скорее всего, дело в этом и проверку надо вынести за пределы цикла.

Можно попробовать выяснить используемый шаблон альтернативным способом, через мета-поля страницы:

```
if ( get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() ) == 'content-main.php' ) {}
```

Второй способ должен работать и внутри цикла.

**UPDATE**

Второй способ работает для цикла по страницам, а WooCommerce осуществляет свой цикл по продуктам, и `get_the_ID()` здесь не работает. В случае с WooCommerce определить используемый шаблон можно следующим образом.

В functions.php добавить фильтр, отслеживающий смену шаблона и запоминающий его в глобальной переменной, а также функцию, возвращающую значение этой глобальной переменной.

```
function filter_template_include( $t ) {
    $GLOBALS['current_template'] = basename($t);
    return $t;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'filter_template_include', 1000 );

function get_current_template() {
    if( !isset( $GLOBALS['current_template'] ) )
        return false;
    return $GLOBALS['current_template'];
}
```

В файле `content-product.php` использовать эту функцию для получения имени текущего шаблона.

```
if (get_current_template() == 'content-main.php') {}
```

Напоминаю, что `content-product.php` лучше скопировать в подпапку своей темы `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/` и править там. Так он сохранится при обновлении WooCommerce.

Для теста была создана [страница](http://test.kagg.eu/so632379/) на тестовом сайте. Ей назначен шаблон `woo-test`. Содержание файла `so632379.php`

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: woo-test
*/
echo do_shortcode('[products]');
?>
```

В `content-product.php` добавлена строка вывода названия шаблона

```
// Ensure visibility
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}

echo "Current template = " . get_current_template();

?>
<li <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Результат [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so632379/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вынести за пределы цикла, если в плагине woocommerce вызывается только стандартный шаблон content-product.php?
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
Ведь только в этом файле content-product.php получается можно делать проверку и узнать откуда этот файл php вызвался.
Подскажите, как вынести проверку за цикл?
Это получается нужно переопределять метод woocommerce_content()

Comment: Второй способ должен работать и внутри цикла.

Comment: if(get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() ) == 'content-main.php'){  }
  нет, не работает

Comment: Да. Выяснил, почему и дополнил ответ.